# Git try checkout branch or default

Tags: git, devops

Let's say I have this branches on the remote repository:

```
./master
./develop
./feature/A
./feature/B
```

I would like to pull specific branch and if this branch does not exists I would like to default to develop or master.
develop is default fallback if feature branch does not exist
master is default fallback if develop does not exist.

I work in a project that has many repos and only some of them have feature branches.
Other repos have master and integration branches and some only master branch.

I want to write a script that will pull all repos with specific branch (feature/B) and if current repo doesn't have that branch I want to pull develop or master.

Comment: "I want to write a script that will pull all repos with specific branch (feature/B) and if current repo doesn't have that branch I want to pull develop or master." - What language would you like to write the script in?

Comment: powershell would be best

Comment: Do you want a script that you hardcode repo urls in, the script accepts repo urls as a command line parameter, or something else?

Comment: good question. haven't thought about it.
I've assumed that I already have those repos downloaded in one folder and the just update them all

Comment: "I've assumed that I already have those repos downloaded in one folder and the just update them all" - In that case, I expect a PowerShell version of what @Grzegorz suggested below should work.

Comment: General advice on `git pull`: consider avoiding it. Specific advice on `git pull` in scripts: almost certainly avoid it. The reason is simple enough: `git pull`'s behavior depends on user configuration, which means different users get different behavior. Scripts should usually have predictable behavior, not user-specific behavior. (There are some exceptions to this rule of course.) More generally, remember that `git pull` *means* (1) run `git fetch`; (2) run a second Git command of the user's choice. You should be running `git fetch`, but then run a second command of *your* choice.

Answer (score 2):

Would simple bash OR work for you?

```
 git checkout foo || git checkout master
error: pathspec 'foo' did not match any file(s) known to git
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 30 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
```

Basically if `git checkout foo` succeeded - done. If it failed, call `git checkout master`